# Where can I buy chinese road group set?

Tags: groupsets

I have heard about Chinese road group sets that imitates Shimano and SRAM products, but I have not being able to find where to buy them.

Comment: Microshift (Taiwan) sells Shimano-compatible shifters and derailleurs. But only a few manufacturers use their stuff in the US (primarily for bar-end shifters). I'd guess that direct clones which may be on the Chinese market would likely fall afoul a lot of country's IP laws.

Comment: I use Microshift STI shifters, derailleurs on my commuter and like them a great deal. The only negative is that they are loud when they shift. But I liken it to a transmission in a big truck than that of a sports car. Fun and affordable. You can find them easily in eBay.

Comment: You also may be able to find them on that Alibaba web site, however i have heard a lot of mixed things about it. Some people got things in a week, some in 6 months cause it got held up at customs. I have never personally ordered anything from it but know several people who have with good results.

Comment: Plus, if you buy something on alibaba, chances are its a knockoff anyway.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what he was looking for! :P @Batman

Comment: @NateWengert AliExpress/AliBaba is like ebay, not Walmart. You buy *through* AliBaba, not *from* them, you are buying from some random small company or individual in China. I've bought a few things and never had a problem with delivery or functionality.